# Can this integral be reduced to an elliptic integral, or to anything else that is easier to evaluate?

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

New user here......I have run into a problem where I am trying to evaluate the following integral (if at all possible, analytically):

$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x) \sqrt{1 + k^2 \sin^2(x)}\, dx  $

To me, it seems that this has to be related to one or other of the elliptic integrals, somehow, but I am not being able to see the connection.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you !

Comment: it seems that this integral can solved by elementary methods

Comment: Thank you, but I do not see myself the elementary method for evaluating this. It arose in the context of a problem I am studying in the area of liquid crystals, and alas.....I am not a mathematician. If it truly is elementary, I would be the first to admit that I am both slow and stupid, and would greatly appreciate having it pointed out to me how to handle this, or reduce it to something manageable and recognizable.....thank you !

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner saying that without providing a solution is pompous and unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**:

It can be expressed with elementary functions, due to the $\sin x$ factor in front of the root. We can suppose $k>0$.

- **First step**: rewrite the integral as
  \begin{align}
  \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\mkern-9mu\sin x\,\sqrt{\mathstrut 1 + k^2 \sin^2\!x}\, \mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\mkern-9mu\sin x \,\sqrt{\mathstrut1 + k^2-k^2 \cos^2\!x}\, \mathrm dx \\
  =\sqrt{\mathstrut1+k^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\mkern-9mu\sin x \,\sqrt{1 -\frac{k^2}{1 + k^2}\cos^2\!x}\, \mathrm dx 
  \end{align} use the substitution
- **Second step**: use the substitution
  $$\begin{cases}\cos\theta=\frac k{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\,\cos x,\quad \theta\in [0,\pi]\iff \theta=\arccos\biggl(\frac k{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\,\cos x\biggr),\\
  \sin\theta\, \mathrm d\theta=\frac k{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\,\sin x\,\mathrm d x, \\
  x=0\longleftrightarrow \theta =\arccos\frac k{\sqrt{1+k^2}}, \quad  x=\frac\pi 2\longleftrightarrow \theta=\frac\pi 2.
  \end{cases} $$
  Denote $\theta_0=\arccos\frac k{\sqrt{1+k^2}}$. The integral becomes
  $$I=\frac{1+k^2}k \int_0^{\theta_0}\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\cos^2\!\theta\,}\, \mathrm d\theta =\sin^2\!\theta\, \mathrm d\theta =\frac{1+k^2}k\int_0^{\theta_0}\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2\, \mathrm d\theta.
  $$

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, Prof. Bernard.......I am quite embarrassed. Indeed it is quite elementary, and I really should have seen it myself.....I really, really, should have seen this. Sorry for the dumb question. But......if one does NOT have the prefactor of sine(x) in the integrand, and has just the radical/square root, then I think this does become one of the elliptic integrals with an imaginary value for the modulus, I think. (The integral as I have written it has k being real, and smaller than unity).

Comment: Thank you very much again. That was obtuse of me, but, I will not beat myself up too much. I did earn a PhD, some 20+ years ago in chemical physics/physical chemistry, theoretical, but sometimes, some days, the obvious is the hardest thing to see. I put enough effort into reducing the problems I am studying to these integrals, and then failed to see the way to do them. Many thanks, Prof. Bernard.

Comment: I agree it can be instinctive to think of elliptic integrals because of the square root. What made me think of a more elementary computation was  that if we had had  $\cos x$ before the square root, it would have been  obvious.

Comment: Thank you, Prof. Bernard, for understanding. The same problem also generates the integral with the same integrand but without the sine(x) prefactor and with just the square root, and that, I am certain, is indeed related to the elliptic integrals with imaginary modulus. Those, I think, are relatable to the usual real-modulus elliptic integrals through a transformation of variable, I do not have my Abramowitz & Stegun in front of me right now, but I think I have seen this before.